# How can I remove ._. files in my VS Code?

Tags: windows, macos, visual-studio-code

How to remove ._. file in my VS Code?

[image]

I can see this file in VS Code on Windows, but I can't see in VS Code on Mac.

I need to remove this file ( ._. )

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is hidden on your mac, for remove this file close your vscode and terminate all terminals then go to the project folder then remove ._. file, if it does not work restart your system and go there (Don't open your vscode ) and remove it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want vs code to not display those items you have to create global exclusion patterns:

1. Go on Settings (`⌘` + `,` / `⊞` + `,`)
2. Search for "hide" and find "`Files: Exclude`" (Should be the first displayed)
3. Add this pattern: `**/._.*` *(this will remove `._.DS_Store`. If you have to remove also the other directories and eventual files add `**/._*` and `**/._*.*`)*

Refresh the editor if nothing changed and you're done